# Shopping for transistors question

Tags: transistors

I am trying to find a transistor that will allow up to 100 mA to pass through it while it is being saturated. I just don't know what value to look for.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: 2N2222A or PN2222A or P2N2222A (if you like weird pinouts.) Tim has answered the fuller part of your question, already.

Comment: That’s a pretty basic spec. How many 1?

Comment: The truth is that you don't need a transistor with specific properties to achieve what you want. An experienced designer would use a transistor that can easily do the 100 mA meaning any transistor with an Ic_max of at least 200 mA will do the job. Then the designer will look around to see what (s)he's already using, what types we have lying around already or what type is commonly used. The 2N2222 comes to mind but also BC547 or the cheapest type you can find with a high enough Ic_max. Not everything needs to be "thoroughly designed" as many types will just work.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at a transistor data sheet like [this one](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/PZT3904-D.pdf).  Search on the word "saturation" -- there should be plenty of clues there.

Typically, if the manufacturer doesn't give any specifications for the saturation behavior at the current you want, then you need to shop for a different transistor.  The example I give shows a VCE vs. current that goes up to 100mA -- but only just.  I would want a transistor that's rated for at least twice the saturation current that I was designing for.